# adding my app to call menu option

Tags: ios, swift

i have app in swift that you can make a call from it i want to add my app to open in menu that when i make regular call i want open in menu apper  including my app that user can chose my app to make call i found this

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

but it for pdf not for call

Comment: You cannot make GSM calls with third party apps in iOS.